# SOAPUI 302 - Moved Temporarily

Tags: soapui, fiddler, http-status-code-302

When I'm performing a post request which should lead to a redirect, the redirect isn't handled propertly.

### RAW format of request

```
POST https://XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:8443/Manager/securitycheck.vod HTTP/1.1
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Content-Length: 37
Host: XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:8443
Connection: Keep-Alive
User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.3.1 (java 1.5)

with following body
j_username=testuser&j_password=testpass
```

With "Follow Redirects" set to false, request above is responded with "HTTP/1.1 302 Moved Temporarily"

### Logs

```
Tue Oct 06 10:38:58 CEST 2015DEBUG: >> "POST /Manager/securitycheck.vod HTTP/1.1[\r][\n]"
Tue Oct 06 10:38:58 CEST 2015DEBUG: >> "Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate[\r][\n]"
Tue Oct 06 10:38:58 CEST 2015DEBUG: >> "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded [\r][\n]"
Tue Oct 06 10:38:58 CEST 2015DEBUG: >> "Content-Length: 37[\r][\n]"
Tue Oct 06 10:38:58 CEST 2015DEBUG: >> "Host: XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:8443[\r][\n]"
Tue Oct 06 10:38:58 CEST 2015DEBUG: >> "Connection: Keep-Alive[\r][\n]"
Tue Oct 06 10:38:58 CEST 2015DEBUG: >> "User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.3.1 (java 1.5)[\r][\n]"
Tue Oct 06 10:38:58 CEST 2015DEBUG: >> "[\r][\n]"
Tue Oct 06 10:38:58 CEST 2015DEBUG: >> "j_username=testuser&j_password=testpass"
Tue Oct 06 10:39:03 CEST 2015DEBUG: << "HTTP/1.1 302 Moved Temporarily[\r][\n]"
Tue Oct 06 10:39:03 CEST 2015DEBUG: << "Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1[\r][\n]"
Tue Oct 06 10:39:03 CEST 2015DEBUG: << "Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=444269D02E53BB0155909417A5DAF809; Path=/Manager; Secure[\r][\n]"
Tue Oct 06 10:39:03 CEST 2015DEBUG: << "Location: https://XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:8443/Manager/lay.vod;jsessionid=444269D02E53BB0155909417A5DAF809[\r][\n]"
Tue Oct 06 10:39:03 CEST 2015DEBUG: << "Content-Language: en-US[\r][\n]"
Tue Oct 06 10:39:03 CEST 2015DEBUG: << "Content-Length: 0[\r][\n]"
Tue Oct 06 10:39:03 CEST 2015DEBUG: << "Date: Tue, 06 Oct 2015 08:39:03 GMT[\r][\n]"
Tue Oct 06 10:39:03 CEST 2015DEBUG: << "[\r][\n]"
```

Whenever the "Follow Redirects" is set to true I'm hitting a 400 bad request.

```
Tue Oct 06 10:40:54 CEST 2015DEBUG: >> "POST /Manager/securitycheck.vod HTTP/1.1[\r][\n]"
Tue Oct 06 10:40:54 CEST 2015DEBUG: >> "Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate[\r][\n]"
Tue Oct 06 10:40:54 CEST 2015DEBUG: >> "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded [\r][\n]"
Tue Oct 06 10:40:54 CEST 2015DEBUG: >> "Content-Length: 37[\r][\n]"
Tue Oct 06 10:40:54 CEST 2015DEBUG: >> "Host: XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:8443[\r][\n]"
Tue Oct 06 10:40:54 CEST 2015DEBUG: >> "Connection: Keep-Alive[\r][\n]"
Tue Oct 06 10:40:54 CEST 2015DEBUG: >> "User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.3.1 (java 1.5)[\r][\n]"
Tue Oct 06 10:40:54 CEST 2015DEBUG: >> "[\r][\n]"
Tue Oct 06 10:40:54 CEST 2015DEBUG: >> "j_username=testuser&j_password=testpass"
Tue Oct 06 10:40:58 CEST 2015DEBUG: << "HTTP/1.1 302 Moved Temporarily[\r][\n]"
Tue Oct 06 10:40:58 CEST 2015DEBUG: << "Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1[\r][\n]"
Tue Oct 06 10:40:58 CEST 2015DEBUG: << "Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=AD2E5269FB5E759E49BFB4B9A927DDFD; Path=/DVRManager; Secure[\r][\n]"
Tue Oct 06 10:40:58 CEST 2015DEBUG: << "Location: https://XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:8443/Manager/lay.vod;jsessionid=AD2E5269FB5E759E49BFB4B9A927DDFD[\r][\n]"
Tue Oct 06 10:40:58 CEST 2015DEBUG: << "Content-Language: en-US[\r][\n]"
Tue Oct 06 10:40:58 CEST 2015DEBUG: << "Content-Length: 0[\r][\n]"
Tue Oct 06 10:40:58 CEST 2015DEBUG: << "Date: Tue, 06 Oct 2015 08:40:58 GMT[\r][\n]"
Tue Oct 06 10:40:58 CEST 2015DEBUG: << "[\r][\n]"
Tue Oct 06 10:40:58 CEST 2015DEBUG: >> "POST /Manager/lay.vod;jsessionid=AD2E5269FB5E759E49BFB4B9A927DDFD HTTP/1.1[\r][\n]"
Tue Oct 06 10:40:58 CEST 2015DEBUG: >> "Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate[\r]    [\n]"
Tue Oct 06 10:40:58 CEST 2015DEBUG: >> "Content-Type: application/json[\r][\n]"
Tue Oct 06 10:40:58 CEST 2015DEBUG: >> "Host: XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX[\r][\n]"
Tue Oct 06 10:40:58 CEST 2015DEBUG: >> "Content-Length: 37[\r][\n]"
Tue Oct 06 10:40:58 CEST 2015DEBUG: >> "Connection: Keep-Alive[\r][\n]"
Tue Oct 06 10:40:58 CEST 2015DEBUG: >> "User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.3.1 (java 1.5)[\r][\n]"
Tue Oct 06 10:40:58 CEST 2015DEBUG: >> "Cookie: JSESSIONID=AD2E5269FB5E759E49BFB4B9A927DDFD[\r][\n]"
Tue Oct 06 10:40:58 CEST 2015DEBUG: >> "Cookie2: $Version=1[\r][\n]"
Tue Oct 06 10:40:58 CEST 2015DEBUG: >> "[\r][\n]"
Tue Oct 06 10:40:58 CEST 2015DEBUG: >> "j_username=testuser&j_password=testpass"
Tue Oct 06 10:40:58 CEST 2015DEBUG: << "HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request[\r][\n]"
Tue Oct 06 10:40:58 CEST 2015DEBUG: << "Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1[\r][\n]"
Tue Oct 06 10:40:58 CEST 2015DEBUG: << "Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8[\r][\n]"
Tue Oct 06 10:40:58 CEST 2015DEBUG: << "Content-Length: 971[\r][\n]"
Tue Oct 06 10:40:58 CEST 2015DEBUG: << "Date: Tue, 06 Oct 2015 08:40:58 GMT[\r][\n]"
Tue Oct 06 10:40:58 CEST 2015DEBUG: << "Connection: close[\r][\n]"
Tue Oct 06 10:40:58 CEST 2015DEBUG: << "[\r][\n]"
```

Results in

HTTP Status 400 -
type Status report
message
description The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect ().
Apache Tomcat/6.0.24

Any idea how the redirect could be handled properly? When I'm executing the same POST request in Fiddler, the request is correctly executed.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like [Post/Redirect/Get](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get) should be applied. From your log it looks like it does Post/Redirect/Post again. The behavior for redirecting Post requests is recently changed in Ready! API SoapUI NG Pro 1.4.1 to be Post/Redirect/Get, which hopefully would help in this case.